# How to remove jitter on cloth simulation?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

Scene: A cloth (plane) falls on top of a stool (cylinder). Then the stool rotates 180degrees, and stops. The cloth continues to simulate after the stool rotation is complete. This is fine, but what is not fine is that instead of the cloth finding a state of rest, it just continues to jitter (oscillating around a rest state).

Question: How do I fix/remove this jitter in the cloth simulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up increasing the "Cloth > Quality > Steps" from 5 to 10 and the "Cloth Collision > Quality" from 2 to 5. This helped with some of the jitter, but I can still see it at the end subtly.

Comment: I also tried changing Spring Damping from "5.0" to "10.0", but that didn't do much at all -- if anything.